# How can I install gedit-latex-plugin without installing the rest of TeX?

Tags: gedit, latex

After installing ubuntu 12.04 Gedit has gotten much better (faster), and I'm considering using it for LaTeX.

I have installed TeXLive 2011 via their own installation script (Ubuntu repositories only have 2009 version), so I'd like to install *gedit-latex-plugin* without installing TeXLive from the repositories.
This should be possible as far as I can see, as *texlive* is only recommended by the *gedit-latex-plugin* package, but I guess that there is some dependency of tex, that is only fulfil-able by texlive, which Synaptic doesn't show me.

Now, I'd like to know the following:
Does anyone know of anywhere I can get this plugin without this dependency?

I have tried looking at the plug-ins homepage, but I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: This site works best if you ask one question at the time. I suggest that you move the question about if the plugin is good to another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to install a dummy package to fool the system into believing the distribution's Tex system is installed, one of the best instructions I have seen to do this is here: http://blogs.ethz.ch/ubuntu/2011/03/14/tex-live-2010-installation/ , it is for Texlive 2010 but just make the modifications to suite your version and platform and it will work.

It essentially means using the equivs package to build the dummy package, for you to install, you still need to install `tex-common texinfo and lmodern,` perl-tk` is used by the Texlive update system GUI Implementation so if you want to run tlmgr with a Gui you should install it.

Comment: Made it work, but removed a few dependencies from the dummy package compared to the description. I don't have tex-common or other repository tex packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install [`gedit-latex-plugin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gedit-latex-plugin) without installing the TeX Live packages because `gedit-latex-plugin` depend on [`rubber`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/rubber) which depend on `texlive-latex-base` (even though rubber's dependence on TeX Live is questionable). It may be possible to solve it via `dpkg`, such as via `--ignore-depends=gedit-latex-plugin`, but I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: I have tried that, but even though I have changed the settings to NOT treat recommended packages as dependencies, it unmarks the plugin when I unmark anythin texlive.

Comment: @beruic Sorry to dissapoint you, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, at least you helped me find the missing link. I never considered looking at rubber. Thanks :)